# How to handle crashes in unit test target in Mac OS application

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, unit-testing, cocoa

In application we can register the below set of code to catch the crashes

```
        signal(SIGILL) { _ in
        print("Signal Kill")
    }
ncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
        print("Exception caught: \(exception)")
    }
```

But I want to achieve this in Unit test target as well. How can I do this?

Comment: Is there something that prevents you from using the same code in the unit tests?

Comment: My project has around 2000+ unit test cases. So trying to find out a single place where I can register the handlers.

Comment: Where is the signal handler registered within the application? Can you apply the same technique for the unit tests target?

Comment: Within the application I have registered in the AppDelegate, in AppDidFinishLaunching method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have the signal handlers to be installed before the unit tests run, you can create a `.m` file similar to this:

```objectivec
// setup.m

static void __attribute__((constructor)) setup() {
    // switch to Swift as soon as possible :)
    [MySignalHandlers installAllHandlers];
}
```

, and then create a Swift class that does the actual work. Ofcourse you could write the signal handlers in Objective-C, but since you already have them in Swift, you can reuse that logic.

```swift
// MySignalHandlers.swift

class MySignalHandlers: NSObject {
    @objc static func installAllHandlers() {
        // do your thing here
    }
}
```

Functions decorated with `__attribute__((constructor))` are automatically executed when the binary that holds them is loaded, so this guarantees that the signal handlers are installed before any unit tests run.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Cristik. This is exactly what I was looking for.